# Correct method of inserting multi-line HTML into iframe using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that looks like this:

```
...
var html = "<div style='font-size: 2em; text-align: center;'>Some text here." +
    "<br /><br />" +
    "<ul>" +
       "<li>A bunch of text here</li>" +
       "<li>A bunch more text here</li>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "</div>";
iframeBody.innerHTML = html;
...
```

It looks ugly and seems like there could be a cleaner way to insert all of that HTML into the innerHTML property of the iframe. I don't want to completely change the way this iframe is loaded in the application, but also looking for a cleaner solution if possible. I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery and went through a whole bunch of google searches. It seems like everyone is saying to just use the '+' operator and call it a day. It seems slow to me to append so many strings like that though.

Comment: you can replace your `+` with `\n\\` at the of the line to make a break, but the text is still in the quotes.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi - No you can't. The current code has no newlines inside the strings. Removing the `+` operators would only work if it was made into a single string on one line, in which case adding `\n` wouldn't help.

Comment: Use quote before all the html code, and one quote after.  Lose the + signs.  HTML won't care one bit about extra spaces.   I'd also use CSS padding in lieu of html `<br />`    In fact why use the var at all?  `iframeBody.innerHTML = "<div style =...`

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, i meant the `html` variable should be a single string by replacing the `+` and the quotes by `\n\\``. it would not make the html tag inside the variable had newlines but it's only for creating newlines of the script. I used to do this and worked well. But, now I don't do this way anymore. And the OP only asks for `how to make a cleaner way`, may be means `eaiser way`.

Comment: @zipzit I thought that in JavaScript you can't continue the string on new lines (must append each time)?

Comment: The nicest solution would be to keep HTML completely out of your JavaScript code. Have an HTML file on your server and load it in the iframe. Or, if the HTML is dynamic and should be assembled on the client, use a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this way (but now i don't use it anymore):

```
var html = "<div style='font-size: 2em; text-align: center;'>Some text here. \n\
<br /><br /> \n\
<ul> \n\
    <li>A bunch of text here</li>\n\
    <li>A bunch more text here</li>\n\
</ul>\n\
</div>";
iframeBody.innerHTML = html;
```

You only need to put `\n\` at the end of the line. It requires less effort than before.

---

I think the answers for this question is vary. It depends on opinions. It's about programming-experience.

Comment: You don't need the `\n` part, it's just ending a line with \ that lets the browser treat it all as one string. (Unless you specifically want newlines in the resulting string, but for this html they're not needed.)

Comment: I read that using the \ characters at the end is not advisable because some browsers might not handle this well.